# True, false statement show html

Tags: angularjs

First up, my apologies for the horrible title but I don't know what kind of property this code is.

I have a list of users,

```
%li{"ng-repeat" => "user in users | filter:userSearch"}
  .container
    %a{"ng-click" => "followUnfollowUser(user)"}
      {{ user.isFollowed ? "Unfollow" : "Follow"}} -
```

In this ng-repeat I check if the user is already being followed by the current user, by `{{ user.isFollowed ? "Unfollow" : "Follow"}}`.

The isFollowed function returns true or false.

```
var isFollowed = function(userId) {

  var following = $scope.current_user.following;
  for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {
    if (following[i].id == userId) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

So if the result is true (the user being followed) the ng-repeat shows `Unfollow`, and if the result is false it shows `Follow`.

I would like to replace those two words, Unfollow and Follow by icons.

So I replaced the text,

```
{{ user.isFollowed ? "%i.fa.fa-minus-square" : "%i.fa.fa-plus-square"}} -
```

But now the `%i.fa.fa` just gets rendered as text. So I changed it to html,

```
{{ user.isFollowed ? <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> : <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>}}
```

Now the icons are both showing, and the {{ user.isFollowed ? }} gets rendered as text as well,

```
{{ user.isFollowed ? - : + }} -
```

Is there a way to fix this, or should I just stick to text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally apply class to icon like this

```
<i ng-class="(user.isFollowed) ? 'fa fa-minus-square' : 'fa fa-plus-square'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<i ng-show="user.isFollowed" class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
<i ng-show="!user.isFollowed" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
```

Or else you can use ng-class expression.

```
<i ng-class="{fa fa-minus-square:user.isFollowed, fa fa-plus-square:!user.isFollowed}"> </i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
<i class="{{ user.isFollowed ? 'fa fa-minus-square' : 'fa fa-plus-square'}}">
```